# Make facebook notify if an URL has hit a like or share

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, listener

I am developing a web+app system and I would like to know if there is any way that Facebook tells me how many likes has an URL I post in a user wall.

What I would like is that when some users hits like, a GET (or POST) Request to my server is called so I can store the external hit in my database without having to update it every time.

Does it even exist?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [FB.Event.Subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) can help you?

From the docs:

> FB.Event.subscribe allows you to define callbacks that will be called
>   when certain events take place on your site. These events include:
>
> - Logging in or logging out via Facebook Login
> - Someone likes or unlikes a page via an embedded like button
> - Rendering of social plugins
> - Comments are added or removed
> - Someone sending a message to your page or a friend via an embedded send button

Comment: Not what I wanted. I want Facebook to make a post call to one of my services at my server telling me that any publication has been liked or shared.